# Implement jquery like functions addClass, removeClass and delay in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, settimeout, delay

Assume $ is not the browser. Now have to implement $, it will take a string, which is a query, it will use the querySelector to select the element. (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
$('text')
```

Now implement jquery like functions addClass and removeClass. (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
$('#test').removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
```

Now implement jquery like functions delay. (Reference: https://api.jquery.com/delay/)
Here I am stuck and unable to implement delay for this case.

```
$('#test').removeClass('blue').delay(2000).delay(1000).addClass('red');
```

Code Sample

```js
function $(selector) {
    let element = document.querySelector(selector)

    Object.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
        this.classList.add(className)
        return this
    }


    Object.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
        this.classList.remove(className)
        return this
    }

    Object.prototype.delay = function(ms){
        // what to do?
        return this
    }

    return element
}

$('#test').removeClass('blue').delay(2000).delay(1000).addClass('red');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .blue{
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .red{
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" class="blue"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery is written in "vanilla JavaScript" and the source code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Comment: Are you using that for educational purposes? Or are you not allowed to use jquery in a project? Whats the reason?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki I am only using this for educational purposes. Trying to learn ho the jquery works in deep.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to implement this problem using queue and task runner. can anyone check if this looks good or can we improve it?

```js
function $(selector) {
    let element = document.querySelector(selector)
    element.queue = []
    element.active = false
    return element
}

Element.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.queue.length) this.runTask(this.queue.shift())
}

Element.prototype.runTask = function (callBack) {
    this.active = true
    callBack().then(() => {
        this.active = false
        this.next()
    })
}

Element.prototype.register = function(callBack){
    if (this.active) {
        this.queue.push(callBack)
    } else {
        this.runTask(callBack)
    }
}

Element.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
    that = this
    let callBack = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function () {
        that.classList.add(className)
        resolve()
    }, 0))
    this.register(callBack)
    return this
}

Element.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
    that = this
    let callBack = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function () {
        that.classList.remove(className)
        resolve()
    }, 0))
    this.register(callBack)
    return this
}

Element.prototype.delay = function (ms) {
    that = this
    let callBack = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function () {
        resolve()
    }, ms))

    this.register(callBack)
    return this
}

$('#test')
.removeClass("red").delay(500)
.addClass("blue").delay(500).delay(500).removeClass("blue")
.delay(500).addClass("red").delay(500).removeClass("red")
.delay(500).addClass("blue").delay(500).removeClass("blue")
.delay(500).addClass("red").delay(500).removeClass("red")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .blue{
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .red{
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; margin:10px;" class="red"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have code that works and would like a review of all aspects of that code, you can look at the help center of [codereview.se] and see if it's on-topic.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Thanks a lot to introduce me to a new way to get code reviewed. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: Looks very nice! I would extract `let callBack = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function () {` and later code to a function. Like `createQueueItem(() => { that.classList.remove(className); }, timeout)`

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.prototype.delay` doesnt have easy implementation as you have to introduce some kind of queue like jQuery uses internally](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue/delay.js). This is because you would like to execute some further logic when `callback` in `setTimeout(callback, ms)` is invoked.

As in your example
`.delay(2000).delay(1000).addClass('red');`

Comment: Hi, I just added an answer using the queue and task runner. Can you check at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61468901/implement-jquery-like-functions-addclass-removeclass-and-delay-in-vanila-javasc/61487474#61487474)

Answer (score 0):

```
const $ = function(params){
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll(params);
  let dealyTime = 0
  return {
      addClass: function addClass(args){
          setTimeout(() => {
                    elems.forEach((ele) => {
                        ele.classList.add(args);
                        dealyTime = 0
                   })         
                }, dealyTime)       
             return this;
      },
      delay: function delay(time){
               dealyTime += time;
              return this;
  
        },
        removeClass: function removeClass(args){
          setTimeout(() => {
            elems.forEach((ele) => {
                ele.classList.remove(args);
                dealyTime = 0
           })         
        }, dealyTime)   
        return this;
        }
      
  }
  
}
```